# iupac name please?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, nitro-compounds

[image]

I am kind of confuse here whether to  number $\ce{NO_2}$ or double bond in the ring.

Comment: The double bond and the nitro group are the two last things to number in this compound. What do you have so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**2-(6-nitrocyclohex-3-en-1-yl)ethanoyl chloride** should be the correct name.

According to *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)*, a lower locant should be assigned to the substituent only written as a prefix (i.e. the nitro group) than a double bond '-ene' ending, since the unsaturation is considered to have a higher seniority or priority.

Comment: Is using "acetyl" instead of "ethanoyl" wrong? Chemdraw says acetyl.

Comment: Acetyl is the preferred IUPAC name while Ethanoyl is the systematic IUPAC name. You can use either.

Comment: @VijayBharadwaj "2-(6-nitrocyclohex-3-en-1-yl)ethanoyl chloride" is not the preferred IUPAC name. You might want to read the Blue book again about the preferred name for acetyl chloride and the omission of locants.

Comment: I think the OP's query was regarding the correct way to assign locants to the substituents. Other than the ethanoyl-acetyl issue, I think the locants I've assigned are correct. Please correct me if I am wrong though.